# Run only gcc tests in dejagnu regression testsuite

Tags: testing, gcc, compiler-construction, regression

How can i execute only gcc/C test and ignore c++ tests (I am building my compiler with --enable-languages=c,c++) in dejagnu regression test suite. I am using gcc 4.4.7 version. 
For gcc 4.6.2 version there is a "check-c" target to run only C tests but which is not present in gcc 4.4.7. I am running the test suite from gcc build directory by following command:

```
 make check-c RUNTESTFLAGS="<someflags>"
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry that this is so late, but I am posting here in case someone happens upon this and finds it useful:

When i am attempting to run individual tests in gcc, I do

```
make check-gcc-c++ RUNTESTFLAGS="dg.exp=*ignored-qualifiers*"
```

That will invoke all tests matching the glob *ignored-qualifier* in the gcc/testsuite/g++.dg/ directory.

```
make check-gcc RUNTESTFLAGS="dg.exp=*ignored-qualifiers*"
```

That will invoke all the tests matching the same glob but in the gcc/testsuite/gcc.dg/ directory.

This is what I do but I am sure that it is probably not *the* right way!

I hope that it helps!
Will

Answer (score 0):

You could always invoke `runtest` directly, like this:

```
cd $GCC/gcc/testsuite
runtest --tool gcc
```

where `$GCC` is your untarred distribution directory (i.e., not the build area). The tests will begin execution at `$GCC/gcc/testsuite/lib/gcc.exp`. You can additionally pass a `-v` flag to see all the commands in detail.

Note that some of the paths or other details may be different in your 4.4.7 distro, since I am referring to 4.7.2.